# ls output does not have color while SSHing to another machine with iTerm2, but does with Terminal

Tags: terminal, iterm

Just as the title says, when I `ssh` to my work Fedora server with iTerm2 I don't get color `ls` output. When I `ssh` to the same server with OS X's default Terminal app, `ls` color output works just fine.

EDIT: All other `ls` output is colorized properly. Both iTerm2 and Terminal display `ls` locally as colored, and Terminal works properly when SSH'd over to the work machine.

The only time I'm not getting colorized `ls` output is when I use iTerm2 to SSH to my work machine. Terminal produces colorized `ls` output when SSH'd to my work machine and so does PuTTY on Windows.

When SSH'd into my work machine from iTerm2 'ls -G' also makes no difference. Still no coloration on ls output.

Also, when SSH'd to my work machine from iTerm2, the *only* thing I'm not seeing color on is the output of `ls`. My prompt is colorized, `vim` works with color, and if I `echo $TERM` I see `xterm-256color`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ls` output with colors (`ls -G`) is not the default option. Run the following command in your terminal to enable ls colors by default:

```
echo "alias ls='ls -G'" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

This and all future terminal sessions will now display colors correctly.

---

If you're still not seeing colors on your remote (or local) session follow these steps:

In iTerm verify that you're sending a terminal type that supports colors. Open the preferences window -> Profiles -> Default -> Terminal. I'd recommend putting `xterm-256color` as the Terminal Type.

[image: Terminal Preferences]

While connected to the remote machine, run `ls -G` and open the iTerm preferences again: preferences window -> profiles -> Default -> Colors. Adjust the ANSI Colors, and turn the *minimum contrast* down until the colors in the terminal window start to show color.

[image: Terminal Colors]

If the remote system supports `ls --color=always`, remove any existing aliases in ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc and update as follows:

```
echo "alias ls='ls --color=always'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I am currently reporting `xterm-256color` as my terminal. I'm updating my original question again with further info.

Comment: See my latest updates, concerning ANSI colors and the minimum contrast settings. I had to do something similar, IIRC I adjusted the "Bright" ANSI colors to match "Normal"... or maybe the other way around. Give it a shot and let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Minimum contrast is already at lowest setting, what do you mean by adjusting the ANSI colors? Should I just try moving them around until I see some colored output?

Comment: That's what I would recommend, again, I think I had to do the same thing when connecting to an Ubuntu machine running under screen. If that works I'll update the answer with how you fixed it.

Comment: Any further ideas?

Comment: What version of iTerm are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3431/discussion-between-aaron-lake-and-pumpinglemma)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. I found that the color theme I used in iTerm (solarized) redefined the colors `ls` used on the ssh host making them impossible to tell apart.

You can try the following to check whether it's not the case for you:

```
LS_COLORS="di=07;31" ls    # this will list directories as black on red
```

If this does show colors, you might need to redefine colors on the linux machine. The following command defines (some) ls colors to be similar to the OS-X defaults:

```
LS_COLORS="di=00;34:ln=00;35:so=00;32:pi=01;33:ex=00;31:bd=00;34" ls
```

To edit the colors on linux, see the dircolors man page. You can also read the following on how to set colors from .bashrc:
https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized#installation